# C++ wrapping template partial specialization into macro

Tags: c++, c++17

I wanted to make the codes more readable and simple to use hence I dicided to put the template specialization into macro. I put in the global namespace and out of any{ } 
But, it fails to compile and compiler says:-
A template declaration cannot appear at block scope.

```
#define EnableSafetyType(x)\
template<>\
struct EnableOperators<x>{\
static constexpr bool type  = true;\
} ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds self-explanatory to me. Don't put it in a block (meaning inside a function or within any other `{ }` block.) Put it at top-level, outside functions.